# Web deployment to Azure VM failed

Tags: azure

I am currently following the tutorial [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/AspNetVMs/docs/publish-web-app-from-visual-studio.md) 
to deploy an ASP.NET app to my Azure VM using Visual Studio. There are two pre-requisites listed for the tutorial; I fulfill them both.

Unfortunately, I keep encountering this error:

> Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer
>   ("XXX.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com") using the specified process
>   ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make
>   sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the
>   remote computer.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)

Running the command `net start wmsvc` gives me the following response:

`The requested service has already been started.`

When I run `netstat -an`, I can verify that Port 8172 (to which I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET app) is listening:

> TCP    0.0.0.0:8172           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

I have also ensured that there is an inbound security rule inside my firewall to allow all connections to Port 8172 via TCP. On my Azure portal, I have added the same security rule too.

Any ideas on how I may fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trial and error (along with copious amounts of Googling), I managed to fix the issue.

The information provided by the tutorial [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/AspNetVMs/docs/publish-web-app-from-visual-studio.md) is incomplete/inaccurate. It is not sufficient to install Web Deploy simply by following the instructions given -- in fact, the claim that "Once Web Deploy is installed, the Web Management Service is started and set to **automatic startup**" (my emphasis) is false. Here is a screenshot taken from the `IIS` tab in `Server Manager`:

[image]

As you can see, the `Start Type` of `Web Management Service` is `Manual`.

After downloading and installing Web Deploy 3.6, one has to go to `Programs and Features`, find `Microsoft Web Deploy`, and then right-click and select `Change`. Click `Next` on the first page, then `Change` on the second page, and one will come across this window:

[image]

Make sure that both `IIS Manager UI Module` (as well as everything beneath it) and `Remote Agent Service` are selected.

Once that is done, when one navigates to Server Manager and click on the `IIS` tab, one will see that both the Web Management Service and the Web Deployment Agent Service are now running automatically:

[image]

Having done all these, one can now deploy an ASP.NET app directly on an Azure VM.